# How to reload the toolbar when the wpf window is resized

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a tool bar in the window and I want to hide the toolbar over flow button
using the following code

```
private void FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var toolBar = sender as ToolBar;
        if (toolBar != null && !toolBar.HasOverflowItems)
        {
            var overflowGrid = toolBar.Template.FindName("OverflowGrid", toolBar) as FrameworkElement;
            if (overflowGrid != null)
            {
                overflowGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now when the window is re-sized, the tool bar can actually over flow then I want to fire this load method again.

How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `SizeChanged` event, which I think is what you're looking for.  In your window's XAML:

```
<Window . . .
        SizeChanged="OnSizeChanged">
```

Then, in your code behind, call your existing function from the OnSizeChanged function.

OR you can raise the FrameworkElement_Loaded event like this:

```
RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs( FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent, this );
RaiseEvent(args );
```

**EDIT**
Corrected the second code snippet to raise the Loaded Event, not the SizeChanged event.

Comment: Didn't quite understand the second part, how to raise the _FrameworkElement_OnLoaded_ for the **ToolBar**

Comment: WPF uses Routed Events.  Do a search for Routed Events for the details of how they work.  You can programmatically get WPF to raise an event as if it had happened normally by using the code I included in the second snippet.  This way, the `FrameworkElement` class' `Loaded` event is fired every time a `SizeChanged` event occurs, and WPF calls your handler.

Comment: You mean the code snippet will raise the FrameworkElement_OnLoaded?
`private void EditorToolBar_OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RoutedEventArgs args = new RoutedEventArgs(FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent, this);
            RaiseEvent(args);
        }`

But it didn't work.

Comment: It didn't work, it never fired the FrameworkElement_OnLoaded event.

Comment: Then you're raising the Loaded event on the wrong control.  You have to raise the event on the control that has the code in your question in its OnLoaded handler.  Let's say that control is called `foo`.  Then you would call `foo.RaiseEvent(args);`